# Creating a new file and add some text to it using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm making a basic installation script (my first to be precise) for LAMP, and I experienced some difficulties:

I trying to put some configuration in a new file, in this case for ssl-params

My humble code:

```
cat > /etc/apache2/conf-available/ssl-params.conf << ENDOFFILE
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
SSLCompression off
SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"
SSLSessionTickets Off
ENDOFFILE;
```

And my humble output:

```
warning: here-document at line 90 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `ENDOFFILE')
```

I'm curious what I can do differently

Comment: Use just `ENDOFFILE`, not `ENDOFFILE;` on the new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `heredoc` syntax, you need to both open and close the multi-line text with the [heredoc delimiter](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).  The error message gives you the hint:

`warning: here-document at line 90 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'ENDOFFILE')`

You opened your string with `ENDOFFILE` but closed it with `ENDOFFILE;`.

Try this instead:

```sh
cat > /etc/apache2/conf-available/ssl-params.conf << ENDOFFILE
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
SSLCompression off
SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"
SSLSessionTickets Off
ENDOFFILE
```